# React Opening Modal On Route Change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, redux-form, semantic-ui-react

I'm building a React/Redux application with a Sign In modal that should open when the user navigates to `/user/signin`. Before the page component loads, dispatch an action to set `isModalOpen` to true.
The modal component is using `connect` to map the modal state to the props. However, when the page loads, the modal component seems to be receiving the modal state before the dispatch from the parent page component is updated. 
I've tried passing the `isModalOpen` down as props from the page component, which correctly displays the modal when I navigate to the route. Except when I dispatch an action via the modal component to set `isModalOpen` to false and close the modal , the props on the parent component don't update so the modal stays closed.

Here is the code I'm using:

User Sign In Page Component

```
class UserSignInPage extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.openModal()
  }

  componentWillUnMount() {
    this.props.closeModal()
  }

  render() {
    const { location, isModalOpen } = this.props
    return (
      <StackedMenuTemplate header={<Header />} menu={<Navigation />} footer={<Footer />}>
        <Overview />
        <SignInForm redirectTo={location.query.redirect} isModalOpen />
      </StackedMenuTemplate>
    )
  }
}

UserSignIn.propTypes = {
  isModalOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  location: PropTypes.object,
  openModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  closeModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isModalOpen: isOpen(state, 'LOGIN'),
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  openModal: () => {
    dispatch(modalShow('LOGIN'))
  },
  closeModal: () => {
    dispatch(modalHide('LOGIN'))
  },
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UserSignIn)
```

User Sign In Modal Container

```
const handleSubmit = (values, dispatch) => {

})

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isSignedIn,
  isModalOpen: isOpen(state, 'LOGIN'),
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  handleLogout: () => {
    dispatch(logout())
  },
  handleRedirect: () => {
    dispatch(push(ownProps.redirectTo || '/'))
  },
  handleModalClose: () => {
    dispatch(modalHide('LOGIN'))
  },
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(
  reduxForm({
    form: 'UserSignIn',
    onSubmit: handleSubmit,
  })(Form)
)
```

User Sign In Form Component

```
class UserSignInForm extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.handleLogout()
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated && nextProps.isAuthenticated) { // true after successful submit
      this.props.handleRedirect()
    }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.isModalOpen === nextProps.isModalOpen) {
      return false
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, isModalOpen, handleModalClose } = this.props

    return (
      <Modal open={isModalOpen} onClose={handleModalClose} closeIcon='close'>
        <Modal.Header content='Sign In' />
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Modal.Content>
            <Form.Field>
              <label>Email</label>
              <Field name='email' component={Input} type='email' />
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
              <label>Password</label>
              <Field name='password' component={Input} type='password' />
            </Form.Field>
          </Modal.Content>
          <Modal.Actions>
            <Button type='submit'>
            Sign In
          </Button>
          </Modal.Actions>
          <div>
            <Link to='/user/forgot-password' >
              Forgot Password?
            </Link>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}

UserSignInForm.propTypes = {
  isModalOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  handleModalClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  handleLogout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  handleRedirect: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default UserSignInForm
```

Comment: first i dont think you need to use connect on both page component and form component. second it would be easier if you put the variable controlling the modal as react state rather than redux.

Comment: I considered using react state rather than redux, but I thought it would be better to keep all state isolated to redux. 
If I were to move it to local state, would I set it in the page component and then pass it down to the form component? Or just keep it isolated in the form component?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue. I was getting the state incorrectly from my selector.

Whoops!